# jQuery - variable strings in function

Tags: jquery

My html contains many lines like that:

```
<a href="#" id="car_small">Car 1</a>
<a href="#" id="car_big">Car 2</a>
<a href="#" id="wheels_small">Wheels 1</a>
<a href="#" id="wheels_big">Wheels 2</a>
```

I would like my script works in that way:

If ID=VARIABLE+'_small' clicked then SlideUp ID=VARIABLE+'_big'

How to do that?

P.S. Also I have created jQuery script:

```
 $('a').click(function() {

 if($(this).attr('id') == 'car_small'){
  $('#car_big').slideUp('fast', function() { });  }

 });
```

And this is working in way I would like, but I need copy and paste this code for every link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('a[id$="_small"]').click(function(){
       $('#'+$(this).attr('id').toString().replace('_small','_big')).slideUp('fast', function() { });   
return false;
     });
    });
```

This is the way to solve this.

Comment: this is exactly that what I was looking for - small, one line code! Thank you very much. Works perfect http://jsfiddle.net/H3pfH/7/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a[id$="_small"]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var type = $(this).attr('id').split('_', 2)[0];
    $('#'+type+'_big').slideUp('fast');
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure about using `split()` here;  if the id was "muffler_belt_small" you'd end up with `$('#muffler_big')...`.

Answer (score 2):

Change your markup a bit:

```
<a href='#' class='sizeable' data-type='car' data-size='small'>Car 1</a>
<a href='#' class='sizeable' data-type='car' data-size='large'>Car 2</a>
<a href='#' class='sizeable' data-type='wheel' data-size='small'>Wheel 1</a>
<a href='#' class='sizeable' data-type='wheel' data-size='large'>Wheel 2</a>
```

And your jQuery could be fairly simple:

```
$('.sizable').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var type = $this.data('type');
    var size = $this.data('size');

    $('.sizeable[data-type="'+type+'"][data-size="large"]').slideUp('fast');
});
```

This has the added benefit of making your markup have meaning rather than assigning Ids that have multiple meanings (which destroys the idea of semantic markup).

Answer (score 0):

You could try the endswith selector:

```
$('a[id$="_small"]')
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

EDIT: and then you can do one of two things to get at the big one:

use `.next()` if they are in order, or you can get at the id of the selected `<a>` tag and substring it to get the first part and then pass that with _big to a selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can extand your code using regexp

```
$('a').click(function() {
  var matches=/(\w+)_small/.exec($(this).attr('id'));
  if(matches.length){
    $('#'+matches[1]+'_big').slideUp('fast', function() { });  }
 });
```